# unknown column automatically added in where clause codeigniter query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

unknown column session_id automatically added in where clause codeigniter query.

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'session_id' in 'where clause'
SELECT `column` FROM (`table_name`) WHERE `session_id` = '30d111cf75477d3f7a67a7d88469f3c4' AND `id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Filename: /var/www/site/www/libraries/acl.php
Line Number: 41,
```

this is my query=>

```
$this->ci->db->select('column');
$this->ci->db->where('id',floatval($data));
$sql = $this->ci->db->get('table_name',1);
```

but it just working fine when i use direct query.....

Comment: what is the value of $data?

Comment: just put echo $data & check whether it has any session variable.